# Enabling OData Filtering on WebApi 2 ASP.NET 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a legacy WebApi running on ASP.NET `4.6.1` where I need to be able to enable OData fitler support to an endpoint.

However, when debugging the controller through Postman, the `ODataQueryOptions<Job> searchOptions` on the controller is always null.

My query string example is;

`https://localhost:44310/api/job/find/odata?Filter=[["Title"%2C"contains"%2C"T"]]&Skip=1&Top=5`

I have added `System.Web.Http.OData` - `V5.7.0.0` reference to the controller.

With the following in my `WebApiConfig` `Register` method;

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.EnableQuerySupport();
        //config.AddODataQueryFilter();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

To note I have tried both `EnableQuerySupport()` which intellisense is saying is obselete and `AddODataQueryFilter()` however neither seems to work.

In my controller I then have the following code;

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [Route("find/odata")]
    public PageResult<Job> Find(ODataQueryOptions<Job> searchOptions)
    {
        ...
        return new PageResult<Job>(response.Result, null, null);
    }
```

I have tried with and without the `[EnableQuery]` filter with no change.

for reference the link I have been using is;

[Microsoft OData tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options)

Answer (score 0):

Any resolution on this? I'm seeing the same behavior. If I globally enable filter via config.Filter(), it works, but I'd rather enable it on a class by class or property by property basic, which doesn't appear to work.